# how to directly read from and write to an imageBitMap

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Ok so I'm working on a project right now where I have to draw millions of pixels one at a time to an image. Since canvas is really slow when it comes to many individual commands, I would much rather directly modify the image data. What I would like to do is modify an imageBitmap, and then apply it to a canvas.

So for example I would like to take this array of pixels

```
[255,0,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,255,0,255,255,255,255,0,255,255];
```

and write it to an imageBitmap without using the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) not an ImageBitmap.